# Intercepting server response after springSecurityFilterChain

Tags: java, spring-security, servlet-filters

In web application I need to send server response in JSON format. For that purpose I used a custom servlet filter and it's worked fine until I starting to use spring security filter chain for authentication. When authentication is successfully passed my filter changing response as I needed, but if it failed  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter catch authentication exception and send an error response in html format to client before than other filters in chain (including my filter) finish its work. So, can you suggest some variant of placing my filter or any other solution for intercepting error responses?

spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Rest authentication entry point configuration -->
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">

    <intercept-url pattern="/api/companies" access="hasRole('ROLE_SYSADMIN')"/>
    <custom-filter ref="responseFilter" position = "FIRST"/>

    <sec:form-login
        login-processing-url="/api/login"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler"/>

    <sec:logout logout-url="/api/logout" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="responseFilter"
            class="my.app.filters.ResponseFilter"/>

<!-- Connect the custom authentication success handler -->

<beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler"
            class="my.app.security.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
<!-- Using default failure handler -->
<beans:bean id="myFailureHandler"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

<beans:bean id="bcrypt"
           class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Authentication manager -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="bcrypt"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                           users-by-username-query="
     SELECT username, password, 'true'
     FROM users
     WHERE username=?;"

                           authorities-by-username-query="
    SELECT username, rolename
    FROM users
    WHERE username=?;"
        />

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Enable the annotations for defining the secure role -->
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

</beans:beans>
```